# invoking test case with in another test case in pytest framework

Tags: python-2.7, pytest, pytest-django

I am using pytest for automation.

Is there any option in pytest to invoking test case with in another test case.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can. With pytest, a test case is a simple function or method.

For example:

```
def test_foo():
    assert 2 + 2 == 4

def test_bar():
    assert [1] + [2] == [1, 2]
    test_foo()
```

Consider why you would want to do this. Typically, keeping tests decoupled provides benefits, like easier debugging when a test fails.

Comment: Your example is not representative, since test-case's  signature may includes fixtures and other parameters.

Comment: One reason that I can think to do this would be to write a super-test that incorporates a set of specific sub-tests, in order, as desired.  I.e., a single test that "pulls in" individual, named tests from, e.g., subdirectories (or wherever).